# Umbraco 7 - Global.asax - Application_Error

Tags: umbraco, global-asax, umbraco7

I am trying to write my own "Application_Error" for my site.

I need to catch 404's (to see what mistakes users are making) & 500's to catch my programming errors. I did this succesfully in my site before I started using Umbraco in the global.asax.

I have tried the following method.

1: I created a class MyGlobal (file MyGlobal.vb in the App_Code directory:

```
  Public Class MyGlobal
     Inherits umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication
    Protected Overloads Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
         Dim ctx As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
         ctx.Response.Redirect("http://wwww.google.com")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Obivously, this is only to test.

In addition, I editeted my Global.asax file and now it looks like this:

```
<%@ Application Language="VB"   Inherits="MyGlobal" %>

<script runat="server">

</script>
```

I already have:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

&

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
```

in my web.config.

1: When I try to enter a non-existent page, i get the Umbraco 404 error page.

2: When I purposely create a 500 error, the system shows me the error page and does not redirect to Google.

Please help as I can not go live without this.

Thanks.

Yoni

Edit:
As I am working in VB, I have used this:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports Umbraco.Core


Public Class MyCustomEvent1
Inherits ApplicationEventHandler
Protected Overrides Sub ApplicationStarted(umbracoApplication As UmbracoApplicationBase, applicationContext As ApplicationContext)

    AddHandler umbracoApplication.[Error], AddressOf umbracoApplication_Error



End Sub

Private Sub umbracoApplication_Error(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim x As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    x.Response.Redirect("http://www.espn.com")
    ' Do your stuff
End Sub
```

End Class

It is not firing when I try either a 404 or a 500 error.

(If I put a redirect in the upper section, i get an error that "System.Web.HttpException: Response is not available in this context.")

Can you help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Concerning 404's, you should look at the package [301 URL Tracker](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker).  This is an amazing free package tracking all 404's.  While doing that it also tracks all renames of nodes, when a node has been renamed, it also creates a redirect to the new url.  Of cource you can also create your own redirects using urls from a previous site or using regex.

Writing your own global asax is not best practice when you use Umbraco, because umbraco uses a lot of things at startup itself.  Instead you can hook into the [ApplicationEventHandler](http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Events/application-startup) events to register your custom code at startup.  The only thing to activate the handlers is implementing the ApplicationEventHandler class.  All classes derived from this class will be called at the umbraco boot-up.

The UmbracoApplicationBase class is derived from the HttpApplication.  You can hook into the Error event of this class to implement your own error handler logic.

```
public class MyCustomEvent1 : ApplicationEventHandler
{
  protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
  {
    umbracoApplication.Error += umbracoApplication_Error;

    // very bad example
    // Response.Redirect("http://google.com")

  }

  void umbracoApplication_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Do your stuff
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
If you need to create your own "404 not found" pipeline you should create an `IContentFinder` ([see documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Request-Pipeline/IContentFinder)). The example below comes from this PDF: http://www.zpqrtbnk.net/CoreInternalsForWebsiteDevelopment.pdf and this [session from Stéphane Gay presented at Codegarden](http://stream.umbraco.org/video/9921022/core-internals-for-website-development).

```
public class My404ContentFinder : IContentFinder 
{
  public bool TryFindContent(PublishedContentRequest contentRequest)
  {
    if (!contentRequest.HasDomain)
        return false;
    var contentCache = contentRequest.RoutingContext.UmbracoContext.ContentCache;
    var domainRoot = contentCache.GetById(contentRequest.Domain.RootNodeId);
    var firstSegment = contentRequest.Uri.AbsolutePath.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
    var root = domainRoot.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UrlName == firstSegment);
    root = root ?? domainRoot.Children.First();
    var page = root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "404");
    if (page == null) return false;
    contentRequest.PublishedContent = page;
    var wcd = Domain.GetDomainsById(root.Id, true).SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsWildcard);
   if (wcd != null) contentRequest.Culture = new CultureInfo(wcd.Language.CultureAlias);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i've updated my answer accordingly.  In short: use the umbracoApplication variable for error handling and you only need to implement the ApplicationEventHandler class to enable this functionality.

Comment: Oh, in case you have already implemented your uw Global Asax, don't forget to "remove" any functionality you have added.  :-)

Comment: Thanks
Unfortunately, 301 URL Tracker is not compatible with my system, as I installed my Umbraco DB with SQL CE.

So I am forced to use option 2.
I am not sure how to adapt it to the Application_Error sub.

Comment: Can you verify that the "AddHandler" is activated on application startup?

Comment: Add info using LogHelper or set a breakpoint.   My guess is that your startup handler did not run.

Comment: I hate to be a pain, but how would I do either of those?

Comment: Sure!  As does any umbraco developer in the mega friendly community!  Create a new topic on the umbraco forums and send (me) a tweet using the #umbraco hashtag.

Comment: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/55036-Creating-Custom-Application_Error-procedure-in-Umbraco-7-(vb)

Comment: dampee: Did you look at that post there?